# Concatenate multiple selectors in less

Tags: css, css-selectors, less

I'm trying to do this:

```
.a:concat(.b, .c, .d)
```

Expecting this result:

```
.a.b, .a.c, .a.d {}
```

Obviously this won't work since there isn't a function called concat in LESS. 
Can we achieve this with something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is not achieved with a pseudo-class, but [with the `&` character in a nested rule](http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-nested-rules):

```
.a {
  &.b, &.c, &.d {}
}
```

On an interesting note, there is in fact a pseudo-class being proposed for the upcoming Selectors standard, not as `:concat()` but as [`:matches()`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors-4/#matches), with similar syntax. It's unimplemented outside of prefixes at the moment, but in the meantime, this is done a little differently with LESS.

Comment: Thank you @BoltClock. I forgot to say that I had already accomplished that with &, but I was looking for something more maintainable, as in my less I have many more selectors, for example: `.a, .b, .c, .d, .e, .f, .g{}` and in another line `.h, .i, .j, .k, .l, .m {}` and so on. That's why I was looking for something different.